# How to select records having array containing the passed in string from postgres/typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Following is the record in table -

[image]

I need to select records based on the batches (last column). I have my end point like -

`http://localhost:3000/batch/Batch 3`

This is my controller and works fine and redirect the call to service -

```
@Get('/batch/:batchName')
  getByBatch(@Param('batchName') batch): Promise<Assignment[]> {
    return this.assignmentService.getByBatch(batch);
  }
```

This is my service -

```
async getByBatch(batch: string): Promise<Batch[]> {
    return await getRepository(Assignment)
      .createQueryBuilder('a')
      .where('a.batches CONTAINS :batch', { batch: batch })
      .getMany();
  }
```

I am not sure as how the query would be formed in this case. I am using `typeorm` and `postgres`. 
For simple queries, I have directly used repository like -

```
return this.assgRepository.findOne({ id: id });
```

Following is the entity -

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column({ array: true })
  batches: string;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  createdAt: string;
```

I need to pass a batch and fetch records which ever contain that batch.

P.S. If you could also point me as how can I update the `batches` would be great.

Answer (score 1):

```js
@Column({type: "simple-array"})
batches: string;
```

batches should be saved in the form `["batch 1", "batch 2"]` and not like `[{"batch 1", "batch 2"}]`

finally query

```js
where("a.batches IN (:...batch)", { batch: ["batch 1"] })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it and it's

I have my entity like so:

```
  @Column({ type: 'text', array: true, nullable: true })
  relations?: string[];
```

I can save using the repository:

```
await repository.save([{
  relations: ['contact', 'user'],
}]);
```

And query using the query builder, returning all records that have 'contact' in the "relations" array:

```
  await repository
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .where('relations && ARRAY[:...relationTable]', {
      relationTable: ['contact'],
    });
```